# Why doesn't @bot.command() work in my discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I made my Discord bot, but here the bot doesn't work anymore. There are none issues in the console. Where is my mistake?

This is my 2nd Class (Commands.py).
My Bot has all permissions in the Developement Portal what it really need.

My 1st Class (main.py) works perfect.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')



def caps_pls(text):
    return text.upper()


@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, *, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)


@say.error
async def say_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('Bitte schreibe, was ich sagen soll.️')


@bot.command()
async def caps(ctx, *, arg: caps_pls):
    await ctx.send(arg)


@caps.error()
async def caps_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('Bitte schreibe mir, was ich schreien soll. ')


@bot.commands()
async def kill(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f'{member.display_name} wurde gekillt. ')


@kill.error
async def kill_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send('Ich kann diesen Member nicht finden.')


@bot.commands()
async def kiss(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f'{member.display_name} wurde geküsst. ')


@kiss.error
async def kiss_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send('Ich kann diesen Member nicht finden.')


bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you expect to happen when you run the code? What happens instead?

Comment: I notice you have `commands.Bot(command_prefix='§')`. Are you sure you are trying to use commands with that prefix? I'm not even sure how to type it.

Comment: Why `bot, client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='§')`? This should result in an error. Which one do you want to use?

Comment: Thanks. Since the code doesn't work when run in the Discord, I would have thought I'd at least get an error code.
I also tried it with an another prefix like '!'. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Eric Jin
I also tried it without client. Like: bot = commands.Bots(command_prefix='§') and remove the ping command.

Comment: Can you send us the full traceback of the error? (Also, you mixed `bot` and `client` in some places, only use 1.)

Comment: Okay, I used only bot once and left client out.
I would like to send the errors but I didn't get any in the console or anywhere else.

Comment: @MausPie Can you edit the question body so it matches your current code?

Comment: @SuperStormer Yes, it's done.

Comment: Why is there no error (quick note: you use `bot.commands()` once, did you mean `bot.command()`)? Is your bot at least getting the messages? Try making `on_message` event and printing every message it sees.